# use one, other, another

Tags: word-usage

I wish to write a sentence and I have the three alternatives:

> 1. I have three tables, one is black, one is green and one is blue
> 2. I have three tables, one is black, other is green and another is blue.
> 3. I have thee tables, one is black, the other is green and the other is blue.

Which one is it?

Comment: Your sentence also has a [comma splice](https://literarydevices.net/comma-splice/), which would be fixed by changing the first comma into a semicolon, by adding a coordinating conjunction, or by splitting the statement into two sentences. For example:  "**I have three tables; one is black, one is green, and one is blue.**"

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct:

> I have three tables, one is black, one is green and one is blue.

The second would need rewriting slightly to be correct:

> I have three tables, one is black, another is green and the third/last/other one is blue.

The third one wouldn't work as written since you have three tables, so couldn't use other twice like that. You could try something like:

> I have three tables. One is black, and the others are green and blue respectively.

Answer (score 1):

"The other" can only be used when there is one thing left. So 3 is no good - "the other is green" doesn't make sense because there is still the blue one that you haven't yet mentioned at this point. 2 is also no good because you cannot use "other" by itself this way. It has to be "the other" or "another". You could say "one is black, another is green, and another is blue." You could also say "one is black, another is green, and the other [or the last one] is blue." Sentence 1 is also ok.